# How to convert NodeJS form-data object into JSON string

Tags: node.js, axios, form-data

I am using [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) package in my NodeJS application to send formdata. I am using Axios interceptor for logging the requests in a file. In `axiosIns.config.data`, I need the JSON string corresponding to the formdata set but currently it's FormData Object.

This library provides a `toString` method but on using that I have found that it returns a static string `[object FormData]` instead of the stringified input. I have opened [an issue](https://github.com/form-data/form-data/issues/515) regarding that but seems unattended.

I have created [a repl](https://replit.com/@shivams136/FormDatatoString#index.js) for regenerating that.

Is there any way so that I can convert my formdata object into a readable, loggable, preferably JSO string?

Comment: use `JSON.stringify(json_object_here)`

Comment: why are you translating into JSON. Just send your buffer into axios!

Comment: @TalESid
Buffer contains from boundaries as well, Also, My concern is not with sending data into Axios but logging into the file after response received. Sending formdata object in input is working but I want the input data on the response interceptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I got [reply on the github issue](https://github.com/form-data/form-data/issues/515#issuecomment-927752502) mentioned and as per that *"this package doesn't intend to implement the toString() in a way to return stringified data. If I want spec-compliant FormData, I'll need to install the other packages mentioned. So it's not an issue but an intended unimplemented feature."*

- [formdata-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formdata-node)
- [formdata-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formdata-polyfill)
- [undici](https://www.npmjs.com/package/undici)

---

I tried below code, seems fine but not recommended as it's based on text splitting and filtering, if text format changes, it might create issue. This is [the sandbox](https://replit.com/@shivams136/ConvertFormdatatoJSON) for the same.

```js
const FormData = require("form-data");

var data = new FormData();
data.append("modid", "IM");
data.append("token", "provider");
data.append("cat_type", "3");

const objectifyFormdata = (data) => {
    return data
        .getBuffer()
        .toString()
        .split(data.getBoundary())
        .filter((e) => e.includes("form-data"))
        .map((e) =>
            e
                .replace(/[\-]+$/g, "")
                .replace(/^[\-]+/g, "")
                .match(/\; name\=\"([^\"]+)\"(.*)/s)
                .filter((v, i) => i == 1 || i == 2)
                .map((e) => e.trim())
        )
        .reduce((acc, cur) => {
            acc[cur[0]] = cur[1];
            return acc;
        }, {});
};

console.log(objectifyFormdata(data));
// { modid: 'IM', token: 'provider', cat_type: '3' }
```

Comment: Yah this is best if someone needs only for text data

Answer (score 1):

I solved It

```
const FormData =  require("form-data");

var data = new FormData();
data.append("modid", "IM");
data.append("token", "provider\nagg");
data.append("cat_type", "3");

var boundary = data.getBoundary();

var data_row = data.getBuffer().toString();

console.log(rawFormDataToJSON(data_row,boundary));

function rawFormDataToJSON(raw_data,boundary){
    var spl = data_row.split(boundary);
    var data_out = [];
    spl.forEach(element => {
        let obj = {};
        let ll = element.split("\n");
         if(ll[1]){
            let key = ll[1].split("=")[1].replace('"',"").replace('"\r',"");
            let val = "";
            if(ll.length > 3){
                for (let i = 3; i < ll.length; i++) {
                    val += ll[i]+"\n";
                }
            }
            obj[key] = val.replace("--","").replace("\r\n\n","");
            data_out.push(obj);
         }
    });
    return data_out;
}
```

Expected Output

```
[ { modid: 'IM' }, { token: 'provider\nagg' }, { cat_type: '3' } ]
```

Comment: This returns the stringified formdata object, not the input data, it's extremely difficult to get data from there as there are many headers also. You can check that [here](https://replit.com/@shivams136/FormDatatoString#index.js).

Comment: @ShivamSharma Take a look here, I updated the answer

Comment: In parallel, I was also trying, see my answer below.

Comment: In your case if there's any new line in the value, it'll result value truncation, in my it won't. Also, if you are returning key-values then return object instead of array having object with keys named as key and value.

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts, Really appreciate that.

Comment: @ShivamSharma Thanks, Now it will work fine